# Best way to inspect the styling of an element in Browser

Tags: html, css

If I have a element which has multiple CSS properties acting on it and overriding each other.
What will be the best way to inspect the CSS properties of this element through the browser itself?

Comment: **vote to close**: Question is opinion based and is no specific coding issue

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  In the future please include your code and describe what issues you are having with your code.   We can not give you opinions or best practise questions like that may be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If we have multiple style sheets acting on an element the best way to approach this would be to check it through computed styles, instead of going through all the CSS properties and styles.

Steps:

1. Inspect the element in the `element inspector`
   [image]
2. Then, go to the computed tab in the style inspector.
   [image]

> Here, you can filter and look for the style/CSS property which you want to inspect.
> The value present here would be the one which is applied to your element.

Comment: SO is not a forum, blog or wiki. Do not open questions that does no. That your questions and anwser is not even posted 1 minute apart tells em that you intentionally posted a "fake" questions to write a blog or wiki to collect reputiation. This is not a blog nor a wiki where you should do such things espacially if it does not meet the SO guidelines.

Comment: There is a option to answer your own question, I just did that.

Comment: That option is to post your own solution if you found a solution on your own meanwhile. But as you posted your anwser nto even one minute apart, it is doubtfull that this question needed a communtiy response in the first place. So it was fake question and that is not the intention for that option

Answer (score -1):

your question is not clear,
but generally,  CSS like HTML read and executed line by line it means if you assign style for an element on first line it will be overwrite on bellow lines if you have deferent style for same element. but for more detailed visit bellow link:

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/css/precedence.html

Comment: far from true. There also thing called specifity weight. The last line does not always oevrwrite a line befor. As exampel `div.class` has a higher specifity then `.class` and will `.class` selector will at no point overwrite the higher specifity of `div.class` even if it is listed last. Another thing are `!mportant` or inline style. But that wasnt the question here.

Comment: generally both are right, there are several thing to change the normal path that explained on articles, like you I write a sample of general rule.
and I guess some misunderstand happened! regarding to the referenced URL all of exceptions and rules described, at the main sentence I explain general role normally!
I guess it's not fair to report without visiting the referenced link and read the article carefully.